# Parse error on Guards (Haskell)

Tags: parsing, haskell, input, indentation

I have the following code

```
reconocerCliente :: Cliente -> Cliente -> Cliente
reconocerCliente cliente otroCliente
       | verificarCliente cliente otroCliente = cliente {amigos = otroCliente : amigos}
       | otherwise = id cliente
```

This are the used functions:

```
verificarCliente :: Cliente -> Cliente -> Bool
verificarCliente cliente otroCliente = (esElMismo cliente otroCliente) && not(any(== otroCliente) amigos)

esElMismo :: Cliente -> Cliente -> Bool
esElMismo (Uncliente nombre _ _ _) (Uncliente otroNombre _ _ _) = nombre /= otroNombre
```

Each time i compile i get "error: parse error on input ‘|’"

Exactly in this line:

```
   | verificarCliente cliente otroCliente = cliente {amigos = otroCliente : amigos}
```

I dont know if my problem is with the indentation (Its done with spaces and not with Tabs) or my guards

Answer (score 0):

The code you have pasted has no syntactical errors: it works fine when I paste it into a .hs file, with an appropriate definition for `Cliente`.

The one mistake that you do have wouldn't cause the error message you're getting:

```
cliente {amigos = otroCliente : amigos}
```

The second occurrence of `amigos` has the wrong type here: recall that `amigos` is a *function* defined by your record. It is not implicitly pattern-matched against `cliente`. Instead, you could write something like:

```
cliente {amigos = otroCliente : amigos cliente}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer:

data Cliente = Uncliente {nombre::String,resistencia::Int,bebidas::[Bebida],amigos::[Cliente]} deriving (Show) 

type Bebida = Cliente -> Cliente

This are my data and types. i modified the "Amigos" field but i keep getting that Parse error on '|'